# elasticsearch _update_by_query update by itself not work

Tags: elasticsearch

es 7.9.1

```json
{
    "query":{
        "bool":{
            "filter":[
                {
                    "bool":{
                        "must":[
                            {
                                "term":{
                                    "data":1600646400
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "term":{
                                    "signature_id":2003068
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "script":{
        "source":"ctx._source['confirmed_count']++"
    }
}
```

confirmed_count can't add `1`.

I also try `ctx._source['confirmed_count'] = ctx._source['confirmed_count'] + 1` not work.

After fix spell error  and didn't get any error, but resp updated is 0 that means update failed.
[image]

mapping type
[image]

the doc is exist
[image]

[image]

Comment: extra dot after source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do it like this (i.e. either `.` or `[...]` but not both):

```
ctx._source['confirmed_count']++
```

or like this

```
ctx._source.confirmed_count++
```

The other issue you have is that you have `data` instead of `date` in your query, so no documents get matched (`total: 0`), hence none can be updated.

Comment: I fix spell bug but not work.  And confirmed_count type is long

Comment: What result do you get from the query? Can you share it? any error?

Comment: I have added more details about the question

Comment: I see that `total` is 0 in your update by query call, which means no document  gets matched, hence why none gets updated either.

Comment: Can you check the "View query" checkbox and show the query that is sent?

Comment: {
"_index": "attack_event_overall",
"_type": "_doc",
"_id": "bsaUsHQBdvxIi_xIBFcD",
"_version": 1,
"result": "created",
"_shards": {
"total": 2,
"successful": 1,
"failed": 0
},
"_seq_no": 17,
"_primary_term": 2
}

Comment: That's not the query, you've created a new document there

Comment: I'm talking about this checkbox: https://pasteboard.co/Js6zEXq.jpg Check it and please show the query

Comment: {
"query": {
"bool": {
"must": [
{
"term": {
"signature_id": "2003068"
}
}
,
{
"term": {
"date": "1600646400"
}
}
],
"must_not": [ ],
"should": [ ]
}
},
"from": 0,
"size": 10,
"sort": [ ],
"aggs": { }
}

Comment: The problem in your query is that you have `data` instead of `date`. Change that and you're good